# Unable to use KDE Connect or GSconnect in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, kde-connect

I was using KDE connect in Ubuntu 16.04 without any problems. Then I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 (no upgrade). And now I cannot use kde connect. I have tried both version of Ubuntu bionic repository and [ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu) .

I have reinstalled the app on my android device but the problems have not been solved.

I have also tried [GSconnect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/) gnome extension, but it did not help me.

Have you guys tried to use kde connect on ubuntu 18.04?

PS: I am connected to the same wifi network and firewall is disabled in ubuntu and I have not changed router configuration.

Comment: Try the MConnect extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1272/mconnect/

Comment: Tried it, but the problem remains.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/

Comment: Finally reinstalled ubuntu in the same home directory and it is now working...

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me (Kubuntu 18.04) was deleting the `~/.config/kdeconnect` folder.

After restarting KDEConnect, my phone was immediately found again.

Comment: Sorry I have reinstalled the OS, so I cannot verify your answer. It is working fine now. I use Gsconnect extension available on Gnome desktop environment.

Comment: Yes, saw your note but thought I'd respond anyway because it might help someone else at some point.

Comment: Bang this worked right away on 20.04 - after many days of frustration. Thank You for sharing.